# Submitting form on page load using HTMX trigger breaks subsequent submits

Tags: python, flask, htmx

I have a small Flask app that processes form input and displays the results on the same page using HTMX. When the page loads, the default form values are used to calculate the results. This is done with `hx-trigger="load"` on the form. But if new values are input to the form and submitted, then the results do not update. If I remove the `hx-trigger="load"` from the form, everything works fine but the form does not get submitted when the page first loads. How can I use HTMX to submit the form when the page loads as well as submit the form when the "Submit" button is clicked?

The Flask `app.py` is given below.

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/results', methods=['POST'])
def results():
    values = request.form['values']
    multiplier = request.form['multiplier']

    vals = list(map(int, values.split(', ')))
    mult = int(multiplier)

    y = []
    for val in vals:
        y.append(val * mult)

    return render_template('results.html', results=y)
```

The `index.html` template is shown below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col">
                <h1 class="mt-3">Submit values</h1>

                <p>Input using comma separated values then click the submit button to see results.</p>

                <form hx-post="/results" hx-target="#results" hx-trigger="load">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="values" class="form-label">Values</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" style="max-width:200px;" name="values" value="1, 2, 3, 4, 5">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="multiplier" class="form-label">Multiplier</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" style="max-width:200px;" name="multiplier" value="3">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <div id="results"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.6.1" integrity="sha384-tvG/2mnCFmGQzYC1Oh3qxQ7CkQ9kMzYjWZSNtrRZygHPDDqottzEJsqS4oUVodhW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The `results.html` template is shown below.

```html
<h1 class="mt-3">Results</h1>

<p>Below are the results using the form inputs.</p>

{{ results }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you provide a trigger event for HTMX, the default one is replaced with it. For a form element, the default event is the `submit`. Fortunately HTMX [support multiple triggers](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-trigger/), we just have to separate them by commas. So, just add `submit` to the `hx-trigger` attribute and HTMX will listen to submit events again:

```
<form hx-post="/results" hx-target="#results" hx-trigger="submit, load">
```

Comment: Does it matter what the order is for the trigger events? Both `hx-trigger="submit, load"` and `hx-trigger="load, submit"` seem to both work.

Comment: No, the order does not matter, we just turn on/off events listeners for the element.